# Move equation label underneath diagram/equation with tikzd

Tags: equations, labels, tikz-cd, commutative-diagrams

I'm doing a lot of equations with tikzcd, and for some bigger equations I want the equation number labet to be on the bottom of the diagram. Is there any way to achieve this without manipulating the width of the diagram?

I apologize in advance for the stupid example :-)

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{tikzcd}
A \arrow[r] & B \arrow[d]\arrow[r] & B \arrow[d]\arrow[r]  & B \arrow[d]\arrow[r]  & B \arrow[d] \arrow[r]& B \arrow[d] \arrow[r] & B \arrow[d] \arrow[r]& B \arrow[d]       \\
D \arrow[u] & C \arrow[l] & C \arrow[l] & C \arrow[l] & C \arrow[l] & C \arrow[l] & C \arrow[l] & C \arrow[l] 
\end{tikzcd}
\end{equation}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`amsmath` will lower the equation number when the display is too wide. You can make it artificially too wide by using a box.

However, you need `ampersand replacement`, because `&` only works when the `tikzcd` environment is not in the argument to a command.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,tikz-cd}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1][1-4]
\begin{equation}
\makebox[\displaywidth]{%
  \begin{tikzcd}[ampersand replacement=\&]
  A \arrow[r] \& B \arrow[d]\arrow[r] \& B \arrow[d]\arrow[r] \&
  B \arrow[d]\arrow[r]  \& B \arrow[d] \arrow[r]\& B \arrow[d] \arrow[r] \&
  B \arrow[d] \arrow[r]\& B \arrow[d]
  \\
  D \arrow[u] \& C \arrow[l] \& C \arrow[l] \& C \arrow[l] \& C \arrow[l] \&
  C \arrow[l] \& C \arrow[l] \& C \arrow[l]
  \end{tikzcd}%
}
\end{equation}
\lipsum[1][1-4]

\end{document}
```

[image]

On the other hand, it's hard to find a reason for this strange placement.

Answer (score 1):

Since I do not have the embedding document, I need to guess.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\begin{multline}
\begin{tikzcd}[ampersand replacement=\&]
A \arrow[r] \& B \arrow[d]\arrow[r] \& B \arrow[d]\arrow[r]  \& B \arrow[d]\arrow[r]  \& B \arrow[d] \arrow[r]\& B \arrow[d] \arrow[r] \& B \arrow[d] \arrow[r]\& B \arrow[d]       \\
D \arrow[u] \& C \arrow[l] \& C \arrow[l] \& C \arrow[l] \& C \arrow[l] \& C \arrow[l] \& C \arrow[l] \& C \arrow[l] 
\end{tikzcd}\\
\end{multline}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Using multiline with the \end{tikzcd}\\ does place the label in the correct place, but it misaligns the equation. Instead of being centered it is left aligned.

Also, why do you use [ampersand replacement=\&]?

Comment: @nancytrain You can also use `\begin{align}
\begin{tikzcd}[ampersand replacement=\&] ... \end{tikzcd}\notag \\
\end{align}`. I use `ampersand replacement` to distinguish the ampersands in the `tikzcd` matrix from the ones in the `amsmath` environment because otherwise they can lead to confusion or errors.

Comment: That does work, even though it looks like black magic. Is there any way to put [ampersand replacement=\&] on the align so I don't need to replace & in all my equations?

Comment: @nancytrain No, as far as I know there is no easy way to install an `ampersand replacement` for `amsmath` environments.